# Mysql Join multiple Table error: not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, left-join

Joins have always been touchy for me.
I am trying to grab multiple columns from multiple tables. 
My left join for `product p num` table causes error: `Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'product p num'`

I've seen this error show up for other stackoverflow examples. I tried modifying various versions but not sure what piece I am missing.

```
SELECT tbls.SNum,tblmar.AssemPart, tblmar.wifi, `product p num`.`Customer Name`

FROM floor.tbls, manu.tblmar, def.`product p num`

LEFT JOIN tblmar ON tbls.PartNum = tblmar.AssemPart 
LEFT JOIN `product p num` on tblmar.AssemPart = `product p num`.`product p`

WHERE tblmar.AssemPart IS NOT NULL 
AND `product p num`.`Customer Name` = 'Google' 
AND tblmar.wifi = 1 
ORDER BY `product p num`.`product p`;
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: don't mix the old school comma syntax for join operations with the newer JOIN keyword syntax.  The FROM clause in this query has references to *five* tables. (There's two references to `tblmar` and two references to `product p num`.  I think you just need to modify that `FROM` line, and remove everything after (and including) that first comma. (I also recommend you avoid using spaces (and other disallowed characters) as part of the table name. Use underscore character instead of a space, e.g.   `product_p_num`.)

Comment: I modified the from line like Jacobm001 and it fixed the issue. I added all the tables because I was having issues up until I had the alias error. So didn't realize my `from` caused it. Didn't realize that `Joins` replace declaring multiple tables @spencer7593

Comment: @spencer7593 also.. the table naming is not mine. It was made that way so not much I can do. however I  know not to name them with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're joining the same tables multiple times without aliasing any of them. Did you mean to join them twice? I can't see why you would have intentionally done that here.

The logic you want is likely this:

```
SELECT 
  tbls.SNum
  , tblmar.AssemPart
  , tblmar.wifi
  , `product p num`.`Customer Name`
FROM 
  floor.tbls
  LEFT JOIN tblmar 
    ON tbls.PartNum = tblmar.AssemPart 
  LEFT JOIN `product p num` 
    on tblmar.AssemPart = `product p num`.`product p`
WHERE 
  tblmar.AssemPart IS NOT NULL 
  AND `product p num`.`Customer Name` = 'Google' 
  AND tblmar.wifi = 1 
ORDER BY 
  `product p num`.`product p`;
```

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the `From` can't be all tables when I use the join correct?

Comment: @narue1992 The problem is that you used two different styles of join. You only needed to join each table once. Each name should only appear in the `from` clause once unless it's aliased (which you don't need here). The `from` clause is everything between `from` and `where` btw.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up 2 different ways of syntax on how to join the tables. You have in your from clause all the tables and then you are joining them again.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a query that references the same table twice.

If you want to do this, you need to alias those tables. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS alias1
LEFT JOIN table AS alias2
```